# Is there any reason I would need to re-identify my variable during initialization even after declaration?

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-errors

I'm implementing an interface.

I have a declaration

```
private T[] entry;
```

then, I have the constructor as such:

```
public Example()
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    entry = (T[])(new Comparable[10]);
}
```

My compiler is telling me that:

```
<identifier> expected
```

at

```
entry = (T[])(new Comparable[10]);
```

Haven't I already done this during the declaration?

Comment: Why do you need to cast at all?  Seems to me that your interface ought to specify `<T extends Comparable>` and your variable should be assigned `new T[10]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is caused by the `@SuppressWarnings` line.
You cannot apply an annotation to an arbitrary line of code.

Instead, you need to apply it to the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have done the trick. It seems like an odd compiler error to generate though. Looks like I need to go look at using the `@SuppressWarnings` stuff some more than I have.

Comment: @SLaks.. What difference did it make my remove `@SuppressWarnings` from there?? Can you explain this a little?